# Evaluating a parse tree in python

Tags: python

So here is an example Tree

```
            *
        +       -
      7   3   5   2
```

This should evaluate to 30. (10 * 3).

But what is the best way to recur over this tree?
Ive considered recurring down to the left side until it hits a number, go to its parent and then go to its right side and evaluate. But what if the right node has children of itself? I guess I could evaluate that node by the same formula, but I am confused on how to implement this! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel that way. I've proposed an algorithm that I thought of. Feel free to tell me if its legitimate or not. I dont need you to write me code or tell the another solution.

Comment: Got an algorithm? Ok, give us code, or even pseudo-code. Reading the site help couldn't hurt http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Ive considered recurring down to the left side until it hits a number, go to its parent and then go to its right side and evaluate. But what if the right node has children of itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the obvious thing: calculate each argument and then apply the operation.

```
def evaluate(node):
  if node.payload.isOperation():
    return node.payload.compute(evaluate(node.left), evaluate(node.right))
  else:  # it's a constant
    return node.payload.asNumber()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply. This is exactly what I was thinking but did not quite know how to implement thanks. I am assuming, node.payload refers to the value of the node, and .compute just performs the node.payload operation on the right and left. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly: `.payload` is expected to be an object that knows how to calculate itself. Probably you'll need two wide classes: for operations and for constants. Note that constants could as well use `.compute()` to return the value, just not requiring any arguments. Unary operators, such as unary minus, could expect the left node to be `None`. In general, the `evaluate` and `.compute` functions can be seen as the same thing: `.compute(node)` could pick `.left` and `.right` if it needs them.